# Можно ли сохранить указатель на результат запроса MySql или сам результат?

Tags: веб-программирование, база-данных, php, mysql

Все просто:

```
$row = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
```

Теперь в $row будет что-то вроде "Resource id#56".
И теперь мне нужно сохранить этот объект в файл. Без использования "`mysql_fetch_array`" и т.п.
Что бы я мог позже достать из файла этот результат запроса и скормить его функции "`mysql_fetch_array`".

Comment: @MatthewP, может быть вы немного поясните, зачем это вам?

Comment: terantul, правильно понял. Есть класс для работы с бд, и я хочу вклиниться в один из методов, где происходит сам запрос. Этот метод возвращает "Resource id#", другие методы, такие как "loadResult" уже обрабатывают результат. Так вот я хочу перехавтывать запрос и кэшировать, а потом доставать из кэша если такой есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ТС хочет изобрести кеширование чтобы уменьшить количество обращений к БД. Насколько знаю сами указатели нельзя сохранить, но можно сохранить в файл полученный результат в виде массива. [тут есть полезная информация](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=962)

Comment: Спасибо за статью, но я прекрасно понимаю, что я хочу написать и как это сделать. Вопрос лишь в том, что бы теперь каждому методу переписывать немного функционал, либо одному, но как Вы сказали, сохранить то что я хочу не возможно(

Answer (score 0):

Нет, но можно сериализовать сами данные (кэширование в чистом виде) или поднять [постоянное подключение](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-pconnect.php). Впрочем, настойчиво рекомендую вам перейти если не на PDO, то на mysqli.